# Authenticate to Elasticsearch using JMeter

Tags: elasticsearch, jmeter

How might I authenticate GET requests to an elasticsearch API using Jmeter GUI. I know using curl I can authenticate using something like

```
curl -u user:password http://www.example.com
```

but Jmeter only has the following options

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[The Authorization Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager) lets you specify one or more user logins for web pages that are restricted using server authentication. You see this type of authentication when you use your browser to access a restricted page, and your browser displays a login dialog box. JMeter transmits the login information when it encounters this type of page.

Some developer posted an example of basic auth [here](https://octoperf.com/blog/2018/04/24/jmeter-basic-authentication/).